# Cómo lanzar una función justo después de que se complete el evento de 'ChangeMonth' en los datepicker de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

necesito lanzar una  función propia justo después de que se complete el evento de ChangeMonth de los Datepicker de bootstrap.

El lanzamiento de mi función tiene que ser justo después de que se complete  el evento de ChangeMonth y que se pinte el nuevo mes (ya se al previo o el posterior)

Los pasos  que necesito serían algo así:

1º hago click en las flechas de cambiar el mes.

2º se cambia de mes y se pinta el nuevo( paso de ver junio a julio, por ejemplo)

3º lanzo mi código

Yo estoy usando el siguiente código

```javascript
 $("#datepicker").datepicker().on('changeMonth', function (e) {
        MiFuncion()
    });
```

De esta forma los pasos que tengo, los cuales no me sirven, son:

1º hago click en las flechas de cambiar el mes.

2º lanzo mi código

3º se cambia de mes y se pinta el nuevo( paso de ver junio a julio, por ejemplo)